# Does the rt2832u chip have enough bandwidth for ATSC?

Tags: tv, sdr, tuner

I'd like to upgrade the audio/infotainment module in my 2009 Camry. I see several off the shelf solutions, but they don't have a *builtin* digital TV tuner and the processor isn't as fast as I'd like. So, I'm considering building my own.

However, there seems to be 2 missing ingredients for a DIY solution: an integrated AM & FM radio and TV tuner? Then, I heard about the rt2832u dongle that can do software defined radio at very low cost:
http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr

It would be amazing if you can build an AM, FM, and ATSC tuner with it. I gotta scratch this technical fetish if that's possible :)

My question is, does the RT2832u have enough bandwidth to recover the compressed video bitstream sent by ATSC?

The answer seems no because ATSC needs 6MhZ while the hardware only has 3.2MhZ bandwidth? But then how is the hardware capable of handling it's original purpose of DVB-T, which is 7 or 8 MhZ?

Comment: I think "I'm considering building my own" clearly makes this question about electronics *design*. Though, it would help to edit it to be more focused, asking just one question instead of a broad "please tell me about the RT2832U".

Comment: OK, can you consider reopening if I change the question to 1. Does the RT2832u enough bandwidth to design an ATSC tuner based on it?

Comment: See http://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/1bpvwf/any_way_to_recieve_atsc_us_digital_tv_system/